# how can get value of textbox in querystring while using url rewrite mode

Tags: php

I am using plain php with url rewrite. I have a search form on page. But problem is that how can i get value of search textbox in querystring or any other method. My url is like this
localhost/names
this is simple but when search form hitted then
localhost/names/search
I am unable to get value of search textbox. I am not using jquery. Please help how can i figure out this problem. Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be in the query string? The POST method would be perfect otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use "GET" in "method" attribute of the form.

Comment: but then url will like this ?search=value. that is not in rewrite url mode.